# Django Database Not Retrieving The Values Of Drop Down Field's From Site Form?

Tags: python, html, django

So I basically have a form in my website. The form fields are only drop-down fields. No text-fields, etc.
Once the user fill's in the form and clicks submit, the drop-down ***values*** which the user selected are being printed properly in my Command-Prompt as I expect them to come because I first print them in cmd to make sure I am really getting the output which the user entered through the form. The form has 5 drop-down fields. The form is shown to the user in their profile page.

Now the problem is that I have created a model in models.py file, which creates the same drop down in the Django database as the form in site. So that I can keep a record of who chose which option. There are 5 drop downs in the database model as well. But when I click on the object model in the database, it shows the drop-down's but the default values of them are not what the user submitted through the site form. The default values of them are just "----" and if I click on the drop-down, then I see the other options as well but the default value of them is just "----". It should be what the user selected through the form. Although I am getting the values in Command Prompt properly but not in database.

I have tried the below code. I have searched many places but couldn't find the answer.

***Profile.py***

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <section id="questionContent">

        Have you completed the first file today?
        <select id="namazOptions1" name="File1">
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        Have you completed the second file today?
        <select id="namazOptions2" name="File2">
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        Have you completed the third file today?
        <select id="namazOptions3" name="File3">
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        Have you completed the fourth file today?
        <select id="namazOptions4" name="File4">
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        Have you completed the fifth file today?
        <select id="namazOptions5" name="File5">
            <option value="No">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <a href="" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </section>

</form>
```

***Views.py***

```
from .models import FileForm

def profile(request):

if request.method == "POST":
    File1 = request.POST.get("File1")
    File2 = request.POST.get("File2")
    File3 = request.POST.get("File3")
    File4 = request.POST.get("File4")
    File5 = request.POST.get("File5")

    print(File1, File2, File3, File4, File5)

    ins = FileForm(File1=File1, File2=File2,
                   File3=File3, File4=File4, File5=File5)

    ins.save()

return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

***Models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class FileForm(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('no', 'NO'),
        ('yes', 'YES'),
        ('n/a', 'N/A'),
    )

    File1 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File2 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File3 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File4 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File5 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
```

So in the database the drop-downs are not showing the default values like this:

[image: Database default value error]

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try doing `FileForm.objects.create (File1=File1 ...)` instead of `ins = FileForm(File1=File1, File2=File2,
                   File3=File3, File4=File4, File5=File5
   ins.save()`

Comment: That didn't help. It does the same thing.

Comment: Can you replace the submit with `<button type="submit " name="form" >Submit  <\button>` and in the views.py before you do the logic and after `if request.method == "POST":` you  check for `if 'form' in request.POST:`

Comment: But that shouldn't do any different. I tried that too

Comment: Try to change the html values to no , yes , n/a so that it matches the values in the model .. fitst capital letter

Comment: The values of the options are already set properly

Comment: in you models.py you have `('no', 'NO')` but in the template you have `value="No"` in the models it is all lowercase and in the template you have the first letter as uppercase

Comment: Yeah perfect! Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models.py you have set that it will Show `'NO'` if the value is `'no'` but in your template you are passing `'No'` which isn't a value that your model is expecting so a fix would be to change your template values to all lowercase so :

```
<option value="no">
<option value="yes">
<option value="n/a">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also solved the problem using django model forms.
Your **models.py** can look like this

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class FileModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('no', 'NO'),
        ('yes', 'YES'),
        ('n/a', 'N/A'),
    )

    File1 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File2 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File3 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File4 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
    File5 = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=CHOICES)
```

and you will create a django model form like this

```
from .models import FileModel
from django import forms

class FileModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileModel
        fields = ['File1','File2','File3','File4','File5']
```

and your view will look something like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import FileModelForm
from .models import FileModel

def profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileModelForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request,'profile.html')
    else:
        form = FileModelForm()
        return render(request,'profile.html',{'form':form})
```

then finally your template you look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AKoa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Forms</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="save"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```